# Laravel 6 always says undefined index: model for all errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am new to Laravel 6 and I have setup Laravel on PHP 7.4, mysql 8 and nginx on docker.
I have being learning and migrating a site to laravel 6 and every time there is a PHP error i get the same error.

Error Exception "Undefined index: model" in CreatesUserProviders.php line 82

No matter where I have a line of code that breaks php, i get this error. Even deliberate syntax error on index page shows the same error. Not sure if I am missing something.

As soon as i fix the syntax error, the page loads. Not sure why it says that error specifically.

Comment: Some files are loaded automatically when the site loads. Check `CreatesUserProviders.php` for line 82 to see what it contains, and fix that first.

Comment: It would seem that errors are causing the configuration to not be loaded. If you've cached the configuration try `php artisan cache:clear` to clear the configuration cache and see if the problem persists. Other than that I don't know why that particular error.

Comment: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1081 Might be of help

Comment: This kinda helped. I have fixed the issue by   adding along with the Eloquent as the driver.  After adding this I can see the PHP errors. It was already there and I uncommented it. Will have to understand what it does exactly. Thanks!
 'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],

Answer (score 0):

Line 82 tries to access an array key that does not exist.

```
$array = [
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue',
];

$x = $array['non_existant_key']; // so this will make your app very sad
```

Easy fixed with a simple `isset()` check:

```
$x = isset($array['non_existant_key']) ? $array['non_existant_key'] : null;
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is needed. I saw that this is called 'CreatesUserProviders' trait. In some 'createEloquentProvider' method to cretae eloquent user. I am just breaking the page in controller.php when it is instantiated. I have no array nothing. Also when i have syntax error on index page, it says 500.

Comment: The code that is throwing the error is from the framework. One should not modify framework code directly.

Comment: yes, if it's vendor code, dont touch it